# How to add simple image upload functionality to WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing, upload

I want to add simple image upload functionality to my WP plugin. So the simple form with upload button. I dont want to use standard thickbox included in WP for this.

When you press the button file selection dialog will appear, you select file from your drive and it'll be added to the input box.
Then when you press "save" button for plugin options it will send with form and handled on server side.

I wonder if there is ready to use WP functionality for the server part.
As I want to save the upload image path also to DB options table.

EDIT: added PHP tag as wordpress is a PHP language

Comment: chubbyk, what have your tried so far? There are plenty of php upload scripts, or jquery upload scripts out there (wordpress uses jquery) but it doesn't appear you've tried anything or put any research into this question yourself.

Comment: 3.3 is also going to change everything about the Media Gallery, which probably means you'll want to design it according to those specifications as soon as its out. (It is supposed to have an option for the styling of the boxes).

Answer (score 1):

You're in some luck-I'm currently working on a mod that would allow image uploads for MarketPress. Here's my skeleton, poorly indented script. This should help get you started methinks?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10240" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile2" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'] == '10240' ){
   $uploaddir = 'public_html/uploads';
   $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   $validfiletype;
if ( preg_match('/\\.(exe|com|bat|zip|doc|txt)$/i', $_FILES['userfile']['name']) )
    $validfiletype = 0;
elseif( preg_match('/\\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf|psd)$/i', $_FILES['userfile']['name']) ) 
    $validfiletype = 1;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File upload unsuccessful.";
}}
?>
```

Comment: This is mostly code I used in another application-it has no WordPress integration and I haven't spruced it up yet. But if you're working on a plugin, you should be able to handle that yourself.